# Distorting a shape in Canvas by Clicking and Dragging a particular border point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kineticjs

I'm creating a floor-plan application using HTML5 and kinetic js.Currently I'm able to create a rectangular container where you can drag and drop objects inside it. You can see it in action in this link http://jsfiddle.net/wQ8YA/29/

The js code to create it is..

```
//create a group
var group = new Kinetic.Group({
draggable: true //make group draggable
});
var rec = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 10,
        y: 330,
        width: 600,
        height: 600
         });
group.add(rec);
```

Currently the container looks like this

[image: floor-plan]

But i want to make it like this..

[image: new floor plan]

In the second image the user can distort the container by clicking on any point on the container border and dragging it.I tried doing it on my own but don't know where to start,what this concept is called and how to achieve it.Please Help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basics of how it's done:**

Your bottom image appears to be a set of 4 cubic Bezier curves forming a rectangle.

The squares on the corners of the rectangle set the starting and ending points of the curve.

The circles set the 2 control points of the curve.

If the control points are positioned on the imaginary line between the starting and ending points then the curve becomes a line segment connecting the starting and ending points.

If you add code to allow the user to drag the starting, ending and control points, you will have the functionality in your bottom image.

You can use Kinetic.Rect, Kinetic.Circle and Kinetic.Line to allow the user to drag the control points.

Since KineticJS does not have a Cubic Bezier Curve shape, you will have to use the Kinetic.Shape to custom draw the 4 curves based on the positions of the control points.

Here's a simple example with 1 anchor that drag-alters the top-right corner:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/t2mhpmrs/

[image][image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var g=new Kinetic.Group({
        x:100,y:100,
    });
    layer.add(g);


    var room=new Kinetic.Shape({
      x:0,
      y:0,
      width:100,
      height:100,
      stroke:"blue",
      fill: 'red',
      drawFunc: function(context) {
        var x=this.x();
        var y=this.y();
        var w=this.width();
        var h=this.height();
        var right=anchorTR.x();
        var top=anchorTR.y();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x,y);
        // top
        context.bezierCurveTo(x+w/3,y,x+w*2/3,y,right,top);
        // right
        context.bezierCurveTo(x+w,y+h/3, x+w,y+h*2/3, x+w,y+h);
        // bottom
        context.bezierCurveTo(x+w*2/3,y+h, x+w/3,y+h, x,y+h);
        // left
        context.bezierCurveTo(x,y+h*2/3, x,y+h/3, x,y);

        context.fillStrokeShape(this);
      }
    });

    g.add(room);


    var anchorTR = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x:100,
        y:0,
        radius:8,
        fill:"green",
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        draggable: true
    });
    g.add(anchorTR);


    layer.draw();


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Drag green circle to change red rect</h4>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The second image in the question has 4 control points on each side.how do i add more control points on each side??

Comment: Do the other 3 the same way that I did the first one...Go forth and code!

Comment: I have added anchor points to the remaining 3 vertices in the js fiddle link you provided.How do i save that code since it's does not have a save option and i want to add the link to the answer in the comments section..

Comment: Click the "Fork" option on the top menu.  This will copy the code into a new fiddle under your account.  Then you can do the "Save" under your fiddle account. Cheers! ;-)

Comment: I've added anchor points on all the vertices of the square http://jsfiddle.net/Lucy1/t2mhpmrs/1/ To add n-number of anchor points on each side do i need to follow the same steps or something else??

Comment: Nice work!  A couple of fixes: do `closePath` and since you've added a top-left anchor you should `moveTo(topleftAnchorX,topleftAnchorY)`: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/da90vct4/  You would not add n-number anchor points on each side.  Instead you would better control the curve by adding anchors that set the other 2 control points for each anchor.  Those other 2 control points are the first 2 parameters of `bezierCurveTo`.  These 2 control points are shown in your illustration as the filled circles with lines leading to the cornerpoints--you don't need the lines. Good luck with your project!

Comment: ok..I need to add the vertical & horizontal resize feature you see in the bottom right part of the first image to the shape i created..how can i do that??